# How to enable Multitouch Gestures?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a multitouch chrome app for windows 8 desktop.
Is there a way to enable gestures (zoom,pan) in my maps widget?
It works when I load maps.google.com but not when using the api...

Comment: Have you found a way to enable it? I am also looking for this functionality..